# How can I compile a more compact glibc?

Tags: linux, compiling, glibc

While trying to create an x86-64 appliance, I naturally wanted to compile glibc 2.23. I managed to do so through

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --enable-kernel=2.6.32 
--with-headers=/path/to/appliance/kernel/headers
--prefix=/usr
```

and

```
make -j4 install_root=/path/to/appliance/root && make install install_root=/path/to/appliance/root
```

The result comes out to over 100 MB, and I look at the Debain libc package and wonder how they got it to be only a few megabytes in comparison. It seems much of the space comes from locales and charsets that I will likely never need.

Is it possible to cut stuff out?

Comment: What takes 100MB? Analyze the output a bit further, at the very least run `du` to see what's taking space. In Debian the locales are shipped separately and compiled on demand, the `locales-all` package is ~110MB. If you want to run in limited space, maybe you should use an alternate libc designed for embedded systems. Why are you building your own anyway rather than use a distribution?

Comment: Use [newlib](http://www.sourceware.org/newlib/) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question but since size matters you should consider using `musl` instead of `glibc`. This also makes all the binaries statically or dynamically linked against that libc way smaller.

https://www.musl-libc.org/

http://elinux.org/images/e/eb/Transitioning_From_uclibc_to_musl_for_Embedded_Development.pdf

http://wiki.musl-libc.org/wiki/Projects_using_musl

Comment: musl is great +1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't build locales that You don't need, remove all static libraries that You won't need, and strip debug symbols from shared ones. That should cut it down to size nicely.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good answer, but it would much better if you gave more specific instructions to do it.